# Transform a mysql result (number) to something else

Tags: html, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I'm searching a method to transform a string value from a MySQL request to something else.

This is the HTML:

```
<p class="secondaire">
    <i class="material-icons">lens</i>
    <i class="material-icons">lens</i>
    <i class="material-icons">lens</i>
    <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
    <i class="material-icons">radio_button_unchecked</i>
</p>
```

I have a string value in my database like 4 for example. I want to do this:

Show 4 icons related with my string value in my database.

I don't know how to do this. I've tried a `for` and a `while` loop but none is showing what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
echo '<p class="secondaire">';

for($i=0;$i<intval($mysql_result_string);$i++){
    echo '<i class="material-icons">lens</i>';
}

echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i didn't know this function intval ! thank you again